# Is there any APIs in ektron to get ecommerce product analytics to my project

Tags: analytics

I want to take the top product purchased by customers from ecommerce ->reports->top product
Is there any way to take those details

Comment: I am using ektron 8.7 . I wanted to display those details in my project as a function

Answer (score 1):

You can use  Order API to achive this.

```
 OrderApi _orderApi = new OrderApi();
 OrderReportData report = new OrderReportData();
 Criteria<OrderProperty> orderCriteria = new Criteria<OrderProperty>();
 orderCriteria.AddFilter(OrderProperty.DateCreated, CriteriaFilterOperator.LessThanOrEqualTo, DateTime.Now.Date);
 orderCriteria.AddFilter(OrderProperty.DateCreated, CriteriaFilterOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)));
 orderCriteria.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo(_orderApi.RequestInformationRef.PagingSize);
 report = _orderApi.GetReport(orderCriteria, _qty, EkEnumeration.TopProductsSortType.TotalSold);
```